# AngularJS - Accept a ui.bootstrap modal with ENTER key

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

**The Issue:**
I've been unable to to accept a modal window with the ENTER key

I have modified the default Plunker to show you what I've done since now --> [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8OeJyEOBxm7B2aVHMyQ6?p=preview)

**What I have:**
Briefly, the ENTER key is recognized by the modal, but it doesn't trigger my function (scope issues, I suspect).

The bad part is that I had to modifiy the `template/modal/window`, which I would gladly left unspoiled, if possible.

**What I would love**
I would love to simply put the `ng-enter` directive in my modal, without modifying the default template

**Extra**
I've also tried to add the "event 13" to the `modal` directive, but I couldn't pass any result in the `modal.close`, so I dropped that road

Any thought?

Comment: If you move your `ng-enter` directive and `tab-index` to the template defined in your html it works. However you must click on the div to give it focus to work. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJzRjNlN0jFUbpahQ9MW?p=preview)

Comment: Wrap the modal in a <form> and put an <input type="submit" ng-click="closeModal()"/>.

Comment: @CorySilva you should post this as the answer. The OP should also make sure that if using multiple button tags in the form that only one button should have type="submit" and the rest of the buttons should be type="button".

Answer (score 6):

Check my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4GsEiCZfU7JumCWyO7Qq?p=preview). You should add ng-enter to "OK" button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-enter="ok();" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
```

Maybe you are looking for something more generic, I'm not sure. Then you might consider watchers. But personally I find this better since we don't have any constant watcher which listens modal event.

Comment: For me, this plunker doesn't allow enter to hit OK when the form has focus.

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you describe exact steps for me to reproduce the problem? And the browser of course...

Comment: Works for me in latest chrome/ff

Comment: if i close the modal using esc then if i click again open me and hit enter it is throwing TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'openedWindows.get(modalInstance).value')

Comment: @s.alem Thank you. Worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I have found that it is easiest just to add the enter event handler in the controller of the modal:

```
var text = "This is the text in the modal";
var modalPromise = $modal.open({
    template:
    '<div class="modal-body">' +
    '<button class="close" ng-click="$dismiss(\'×\')">×</button>'+
    '<h3 ng-bind="body"></h3>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="modal-footer">'+
    '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close(\'ok\')">OK</button>'+
    '<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="$dismiss(\'cancel\')">Cancel</button>'+
    '</div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $document) {
        $scope.body = text;

        var EVENT_TYPES = "keydown keypress"
        function eventHandler(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                $scope.$close('ok');
            }
        }
        $document.bind(EVENT_TYPES, eventHandler);
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            $document.unbind(EVENT_TYPES, eventHandler);
        })
    }
}).result;
```

Answer (score 4):

AngularJS support this be default.

Add a `<form>` tag in your template (modal.html) and add `ng-submit` directive
e.g.

```
<form name="questionForm" ng-submit="ok()">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
  </div>
  // the rest of the code here
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add a form if you're not creating an actual form.
It totally breaks the semantic HTML, thus also breaking accessibility by default.

Comment: I assumed, the "rest of the code" contains all the input groups.

Comment: Well, a form is supposed to be used to send data around.
A modal can be used for whatevz, like warning or confirmation.

Comment: I disagree. A modal can also be used as data submission. E.g. entering quick comment on a post.

Comment: Definitely. It's the other way around that should not be done, that is, using `form` when *not* sending data.

Comment: You have to remember, you're using angular, which means you have to make sacrifices with your markup. Whether you should use a form *only* when you send data is irrelevant and simply semantic. But with regards to adding this to the base `modal.html` template, a better practice would be to dynamically designate the specific template for whatever action you're presenting to the user. That way, you could have one template for your form and another template for a simple warning or dialog.