# Trigger OK click by pressing enter in ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a simple ui-bootstrap modal with a template like this:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {{body}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="cancel()">
        Cancel
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
            ng-click="ok()">
        OK
    </button>
</div>
```

Default behaviour of the modal is that the modal is closed if I press Escape. In the same way, I want the ok() method to be triggered if I press Enter. How do I do that?

Comment: Look at this example https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884263. Its the same as plain javascript enter, just wrapped in a directive.

Comment: Good, but where should I add the directive?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that it is about the popup submit. Than your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633422/angularjs-accept-a-ui-bootstrap-modal-with-enter-key

Comment: These solutions works for me but only if some element in the modal is focused, which is not the case.

Comment: Anyway you need to have the focuse in the modal to be able to hit enter and submit.

Comment: Ah, the obvious solution is then just to focus one of the elements! Thanks Diana!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Diana R who led me to this answer:

I can use a ng-enter directive, as described here: https://gist.github.com/EpokK/5884263

That will allow my modal to listen fors the Enter key. But focus needs to be in the modal for it to work. So I also create a directive that I call focused:

```
angular.module('webApp').directive('focused', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
            var model = $parse(attributes.focused);
            $scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element[0].focus();
                    });
                }
            });

            // set attribute value to 'false' on blur event:
            element.bind('blur', function () {
                if (model && model.assign) {
                    $scope.$apply(model.assign($scope, false));
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then I update my modal template so that it looks like this:

```
<div ng-enter="ok()">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{body}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="cancel()">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                focused="true"
                ng-click="ok()">
            OK
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the focused="true" directive is inside the wrapping div with the ng-enter directive, the enter key will trigger the ok() method.

Comment: Great that I could somehow help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for more 'out-of-the box' solution** I recommend using [ng-focus-if](https://github.com/hiebj/ng-focus-if).

It is far more capable, but here it could be used to focus the desired element. Just mark the confirmation button:

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()">
       Cancel
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()" focus-if>
       OK
    </button>
 </div>
```

Now by clicking either `space` or `enter` will trigger the OK button. You can also navigate with `tab` button.